# Should I be including the FOREIGN KEY when exporting my SQL schema from Workbench?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, export

I export my SQL form MySQL Workbench and noticed there is an option to *not* including the `FOREIGN KEY` in the SQL file. Is it better to export with a foreign key or without?

Comment: I can't think of why you *would not* want the referential integrity.  Granted, it only matters for INNODB tables - MyISAM doesn't enforce referential integrity.

Comment: +1 Didn't know it only mattered for InnoDB.

Comment: Yeah, MySQL is good/bad for that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the foreign key if you plan on using the schema for something critical.  Without the foreign keys, you will jeopardize the integrity of your data.